# Why didn't I get *Hello World*?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

Description of [Hello World](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/hello-world)

> make your very first post during Winter Bash, scoring 1 or more

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605666/windows-form-save-textbox-input-to-list-in-different-class-using-c-sharp/20605745#20605745) was my first post during winter bash. +1 and an accept. Why didn't I get it?

Comment: (You make a fair point - "first" is an ambiguous modifier here.)

Comment: @Jaydles indeed, something like "make your very first post *on the  site* during Winter Bash, scoring 1 or more" will prevent such confusions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While that was your first post during Winter Bash, it was not your very first post. To get Hello World, you have to post something (that gets upvoted!) on a site you've never posted on before.

Comment: Oh yeah. I didn't understand that description. THANKS!!!!!

Comment: I'm assuming this is the same for this year's Kofia hat?

Comment: @Doorknob冰 I believe so.

Comment: Does that mean that we aren't eligible for Kofia on most of our sites, then? :/

Answer (score 6):

That was not your **very first** post ever on Stack Overflow. You had a lot of posts before Winterbash.